# How to simulate sensors with Visual Studio 2015 and Windows 10?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, sensors, windows-10, uwp

I'm trying to develop a simple Windows 10 app and I wanted to simulate a Pedometer for testing. How can I do that? And what about other type of sensors, can I simulate them too?

Comment: Yes.  In order to give meaningful answers, we would need to know about the sensor you are attempting to simulate, how it connects to the windows machine, and what programming language you wished to use.

Comment: @ravenspoint he's asking how he can test an app which accesses the device's pedometer (and other sensor data) with his testing device not having a pedometer sensor.

Comment: @sibbl Thanks for clarification.  Can you edit the question to make it clearer?  It still seems impossibly general to be answered sensibly.

Comment: I wanted to test a virtual device instead of buying the thing. Apparently I can use [Windows sensor driver sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/sensors/Pedometer), but after building and signing the driver I'm unable of installing it. Error: An error accrued.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found a solution.

Microsoft provides sample drivers [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples) and there you can find sensors folder. So download what you need, compile and deploy.

To compile you need [Windows Driver Kit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557573(v=vs.85).aspx).

If you're deploying to a x64 machine the drivers has to be signed. I had trouble signing the drivers so I [booted](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=StkR3D2d5WI) Windows 10 with no driver signature enforcement and deployed the driver using DevCon. Check the driver INF once compiled to see the installation instructions.